# How to store data in file date wise in java(Android)

Tags: java, android, storage

I want to store data in android application date wise, i.e different data for different day. The data will be just integer values and meanwhile want to retrieve it date wise only. i want to store it in a single file. and then want to display it in a chart format in android datewise.. so is there any way i can do it. or can anyone guide me. 
Thanks

Comment: why don't you use sqlite database. Database will more faster and convenient way to do that

Comment: which kind of calculation you required. Arithmetic?

Comment: yes. adding all together and then divide them by some number to get single value.. but it will be for one day and similar for another day.

Comment: thats why I am talking about sqlite because  you can easily do this stuffs by 2 or 3 line of query.

Comment: ok thanks i will try that. but besides that is there any way to do do with simple file system android is havin?

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia . i have tried to add data like in two column "DATE" and "VALUE".. 2013-1-10 , 40 -- 2013-1-10, 45 -- 2013-1-11, 33... Like this.. In this i want to retrieve values date wise i.e for date 10 there are two values and for date 11 there is one value.. if there are more than on entry for same day i want to add them and get result..  The problem is (1) I want date should be added automatically as it changes .. (2) i should be able to retrieve values date wise because he dont put date himself.. and then then for differnt dates i want to plot a chart between dates and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look on SQLite Storage.if you want store it in table format. Which can store the values in table format and it will be easy for you to retrive. I think this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming below are file contents. 
Read all contents of file in StringBuffer and then get  daywise contents by spliting based on 
"-------EOD----". This will return daywise text.

```
12/02/2014 1111222222222
-------EOD----
11/02/2014 1111222222222
-------EOD----
10/02/2014 1111222222222
-------EOD----
```

Comment: thanks.. but there will be multiple values for one day and i have to collectively combine it by applying some calculations and convert it into single value.. and same applies for different dates..because i am using aChartEngine so there should be a single value for single day. how i can do that? any example to help?